# User input in date time format Python

Tags: python, datetime, user-input

I need to get date and time from the user and convert it to epoch. I'm pretty new to Python, so don't judge the question harshly =)
I've done my research and if I understand correctly, the only way to get the input from a user in Python 3.x is through input() which retrieves either a string or an int. My current plan is to use input(), parse the string with dateutil parser, and then do something like:

```
import time
time_now = time.strptime('2019-08-30 18:37:06', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time_epoch = time.mktime(time_now)
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this? Maybe, there is a version of input() or a function to achieve this and I'm reinventing the wheel? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's a little cumbersome to get the user to enter a valid datetime string you could always ask for each parameter 1 by 1 (First enter the year, then the month, etc)

Comment: input() always gives you a string - never an int.

Comment: You can also make it one line: ```int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date_time, pattern)))```

Comment: @PatrickArtner Python3*. Python2 input() will convert a number to int.

Comment: @MY for an input of `'2019-08-30 18:37:06''` python 2.7 would not give you an integer - you'll get an `SyntaxError: invalid token`. Python 2 is end of live  [in about 4 more months](https://pythonclock.org/) ... you would need `raw_input()` to get a string. This is marked `python` -not `python 2.x` and 3 is the previlant one now -if version specific behaviour was wanted,python 2.7 should have been tagged.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, you generalized to "input() never gives you an int", which is incorrect for python2, as @MYGz noted: `$ python2 -c "print(type(input()))"
42
<type 'int'>`

Comment: @nyov: let me quote it for you from the question: `the input from a user in Python 3.x is through input() which retrieves either a string or an int` ... - there was _never_ any mention of Python 2.x before MYGz brought it up. And for the planned input even python 2 does not give you an int - it crashes.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The Q stating it can give a string or int could then be considered an indication for them using python2, there was also _never_ any mention of python3. just saying.

Comment: @nyov I quoted _directly from the question_ ... `I've done my research and if I understand correctly, the only way to get the input from a user in` **`Python 3.x`** `is through input() which retrieves either a ` **`string or an int.`** ...just sayin

Comment: @PatrickArtner You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.3 or newer, you can simply call the `timestamp` method of the `datetime` object to get the epoch timestamp. No need to import `time`.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> value = parse('2019-08-31 12:20')
>>> value.timestamp()
1567246800.0
```

Note that you may wish to set up handling of invalid user input that can't be parsed. You can do this by catching any `ValueError` exceptions:

```
try:
    value = parse(input('Date: '))
except ValueError:
    # user input couldn't be parsed -- handle this however you need to
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar

MM,DD,YYYY = map(int,input().split())

day = calendar.weekday(YYYY,MM,DD)

daynumber =[
'MONDAY','TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY','THURSDAY','FRIDAY','SATURDAY','SUNDAY'
]
print(daynumber[day])
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.